# ROO is not generating some aj files

Tags: spring-roo

When I run the following command to generate `ProductSubProductSub` integration test with domain class it generates the following files.

The command ran is

```
test integration --entity ~.domain.ProductSubProductSub

SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubDataOnDemand.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubIntegrationTest.java
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
Created SRC_TEST_JAVA\com\monkey\domain\ProductSubProductSubDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
```

but when I try to do the sam with `PspsModifierCodePosIds` class it doesn't generate _ROO_DataonDeman.aj file but rest of the aj files are generated.

the command that ran is `test integration --entity ~.domain.PspsModifierCodePosIds`

What can be the reason? Any hint?

Comment: Cold you provide more info about the Spring Roo version are you using and some log.roo to be able to check your problem? Regards

Comment: I use 1.3.2 version.  I don't use log.roo. It doesn't fail. Can any hibernate mapping cause this to stop generating the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason, I found was I had removed `@RooJpaActiveRecord`  annotation. it removed the above `_ROO_DataonDeman.aj` file. If we are having Repository then that also generates the above aj file. However, it's not clear why it force to generate Repository for the object.